# Tagging a friend using@ and match it using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have made a form where the user can tag his friends like in Facebook. So suppose the user tag a user like `@abc sharma`. According my code I am taking the content from that div and match it with the given variable i.e.:

```
var word=/@(\w+)/ig;
```

It will remove the `@abc` and put the `abc sharma`, so it will show like this `abc sharma sharma` – I want to replace the whole name after `@ and put the name.

Comment: Do you have more code to share?

Comment: _“I want to replace the whole name after `@` and put the name”_ – well then you’d need to _match_ the whole name first, which `(\w+)` of course doesn’t do. And you would need to be able to distinguish between a  following “word” that is actually part of a user name, and one that is _just_ a word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way to do this is by checking the complete string starting with @ and then split it after @ to obtain required username. it is not efficient but might solve your issue..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex to match:

```
var word = /@(.*)/ig;
```